# Question warning without asking a question!

Tags: support, user-accounts, asking-questions

I have never asked a question on mathoverflow.net, yet when I was about to ask my first question, the site flagged a warning regarding the question not being well received, is this normal behavour? This is my first question on mathoverflow, thanks, in anticipation.

Comment: I'm confused. I see two questions under your account, both deleted. I have not the slightest idea what could trigger whatever it is you're describing above. Can you link to it?

Comment: clarification, the question was on mathoverflow.net, not the meta.mathoverflow.net site, my meta account has two questions but the math one has only answers, no questions!

Comment: Yes, and......? That's where I looked. I still see two questions at mathoverflow.net, both deleted.

Comment: What @ToddTrimble is telling you is that there are deleted questions to your (main) account. You cannot see them normally, but a moderator can. It seems you in fact did ask question on MO that were deleted and *therefore* you get the warning.

Comment: Oh, this was really old, when maybe I was new to site, I didn't see it on the questions asked category, so, the confusion.

Comment: @quid It makes sense now; thanks. For what it's worth, the questions were from last November. One was on arc lengths; the other was a soft question on poets/musicians.

Comment: As an aside, would a question unanswered for one week, on math.stackexchange.com and +1 vote be a good question to send to mathoverflow.net?

Comment: Not necessarily; it all depends on the question. In this case, you must mean this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436743/svd-methods-for-minimal-polynomial It's a little hard for me to say what the reception here would be, but my instinct is that it might not stay open.

Answer (score 3):

It is a feature of the site that users that have asked question that were not well received get an automatic warning. See [Warn new users when they ask a question after a previous question is closed, downvoted, or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow) for example.

It is important to note that deleted content counts, too. As explained by Todd Trimble you have some (old) deleted questions to your account (that you yourself do not normally see and apparently forgot about) but hat trigger this warning.

A user that really never asked a question would not get the warning.

When your future questions are better received the warning will not appear anymore.